# Php Imagick not working after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, ghostscript, imagick

I am getting an error while converting pdf to image file on server but working on local system.

My **Php Script**

```
 $img = new \Imagick();
 $image = file_get_contents($file);
 $img->readImageBlob($image);
 $response = $img->getnumberimages();
```

**Error Occurred**

```
Unrecoverable error: typecheck in .bind
Operand stack:
    --nostringval--  typecheck  --nostringval--  currentglobal  .currentglobal
```

**System Configurations**

***Local System Configuration***

**Imagick:** ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-09-28

**UBUNTU:** 14.04 LTS

**PHP:** PHP 7.0.32-4+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

**gs:** 9.25

***Server System Configuration***

**Imagick:** ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28

**UBUNTU:** 16.04.1 LTS

**PHP:** PHP 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

**gs:** 9.25

I have trying to revert version of Imagick to 6.7 but not able to revert the version

Also I have try to change policy.xml file but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting Image Magick most likely won't do you any good anyway, since that is a Ghostscript error message.

Without seeing the input file I can't guess at what's wrong, but in the absence of that you have 2 choices;

1) Revert your Ghostscript version to 9.23 and try again.

2) Try building Ghostscript from source, its possible that the package maintainers have made some change which isn't in the vanilla sources, and is only exposed on the later version of Ubuntu.

You could also try running Ghostscript on the command line and see what happens on the two systems. You'll need to get the command line from polixy.xml and replace the various variables with the correct filenames.

You can try that on both systems to see what happens. Finally, you can compare the binary size of the Ghostscript executable, to see if they are actually the same on the two systems. If they are not you could copy the working one from your local system to your server and see if that works.

Comment: thanks for time. But how do I revert gs version. I have try sudo apt-get install ghostscript=9.23 but giving me error like => E: Version '9.23' for 'ghostscript' was not found

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Linux expert. If it were me I'd just get the binary from the Ghostscript download site at www.ghostscript.com and try that (old binaries are still available I think), or build the executable from source.